# How do I get my css transition to work with this styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hey I'm having trouble getting my menu container to transition from the right. It just wants to snap in and out with zero transition. I'm passing in true/false.

styled component

```js
const Container = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: ${e => e.theme.colors.main};
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: ${props => (props.menuOpen ? '0' : '-300px')};
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 2s ease;
`;
```

reactjs component

```js
const Menu = ({menuOpen, setMenuOpen}) => {
  return (
    <Container menuOpen={menuOpen}>
      <List>
        <Item>
          <a href="#intro">Home</a>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <a href="#works">Works</a>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </Item>
      </List>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: I found the issue -,-.. {menuOpen && <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen} />}